# The Mystery Behind mxyzplk's Misshapen and Non-Thematic Avatar

Tags: discussion, moderators, just-for-fun

mxyzplk is - and has been for a long while - a very active user and moderator. Ever since I've started reading RPG.SE, every time I visited the site, I've seen his signature on post after post, either providing quality content or helpful moderation.

However, one thing I couldn't figure out was: why did he choose such a *bizzare* avatar?

[image]

It was really odd, and didn't fit the theme of the site.

And then I would click on his avatar,

[image]

and all would become clear. What I was seeing

[image]

wasn't quite the thing that everyone else was seeing.

[image]

(As in, it's not a misshapen, shrugging, single-toothed Looney-Tunes-style gold-digger.)

[image]

And to this day, this optical correction keeps haunting me.

Comment: my avatar on the other hand is completely 100% thematic ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: No matter how hard I look I cannot see what you are. I feel like I did when I was unable to do the magic eye things.

Comment: So you've been seeing Yosemite Sam all this time? (Via a Mr. Magoo-like vision problem?)

Comment: Now I can’t unsee the melting Yosemite Sam.  It’s like the [Bunny Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit–duck_illusion).

Comment: @doppelgreener Well, on the one hand, none of yours were playing tricks with my eyes so far. On the other hand, you share a name with D&D's resident shapeshifter, but you picked the one Crystal Gem who can't shapeshift *at all*, so...

Comment: @Rubiksmoose It's okay, on some days it goes back and forth for me as well.

Comment: And here my optical illusion of it was always a close up shot of the eye of a male wood duck.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer ...I can *sort of* see it...?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's a picture of [Venger](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Venger), the force of evil and villain of the [*Dungeons & Dragons* cartoon show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)) from the mid-80s.

He was voiced by Peter Cullen, a.k.a. Optimus Prime and Eeyore the donkey.

Venger has wings and can fly. He rides a horse that does not have wings, yet also can fly.

The show is campy and did not age well, but I recommend watching it anyway.

So the avatar is entirely thematic due to its obvious connection to D&D.

Comment: So that's who that is! I always wondered but never thought to ask.

Comment: I remember that lol. I have a DVD with them

Comment: In other words, I have the *most* thematic avatar on the site!  You kids nowadays...

Comment: This is one of the most famous cartoons here in Brazil. How is it so unkown around here? Haha. It's incredibly thematic!

Comment: Btw, there is argument if the horse can fly. Some people say that Venger actually carries the horse while flying :P Also I'd argue that Venger is not the force of evil and antagonist - the Dungeon Master is.

Comment: @HellSaint Venger is literally referred to as the "force of evil" in the title sequence. You are correct though, the Dungeon Master seems to create most of the conflict.

Comment: @mxyzplk I always thought your dude was a stern pale-faced man with a 60s mustache, not that  was a gargoyle-looking fellow with his mouth open.

Comment: Coincidentally, I watched a couple of episodes of the cartoon as a kid, and I instantly remembered who he was when I first saw mxyzplk's avatar in full resolution. Still doesn't stop the 32x32 version from playing tricks on my eyes... :P

Comment: @HellSaint  Obrigado, Brazil!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrp2nmfzxio