# Hidden gem in DMG errata

Tags: discussion, just-for-fun

### Mage Furnishings (p. 300).

> A roll of 73 produces a sextant, not a sexton.

### Sexton

[image: Sexton]

### Sextant

[image: Picture of sextant]

Comment: TIL if I'm very lucky pre-errata I can manifest an official of a church. Presumably someone gets a quest to return them safely to their home?

Comment: I'm a bit confused why there are closed votes when there's a [just-for-fun] tag, meanwhile [this "question"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026) is open. Though I'll admit I don't quite know how all that stuff works

Comment: Would be improved by appending a question, with the current post as context.

Answer (score 7):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexton_(artillery)), this is also called a Sexton. And it might be useful.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexton_(artillery)]

Comment: This would be an upgrade on Tucker's Kobolds.